# How can I communicate with a Vivotek Network Camera within an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

How would I go about implementing control for a Vivotek Network Camera within my iPhone application?  Is there a publicly available SDK for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the Vivotek [Software Integration Alliance Program.](http://www.vivotek.com/alliance/siaprogram.php) They'll be able to supply you with SDK's etc, but the code you have to do yourself.

Comment: Thanks for detail but can you explain me the steps to join this and after that what we get through and that what to implementation needed for this application.

Comment: Step 1: follow the link, step 2: send mail til Vivotek as stated on the web page, step 3: sign NDA to join, step 4: well, that would be covered by NDA...

Comment: To join,i follow the step but i did not get any reply from that side. Like as you say for NDA. so what to do now.

Comment: I really doubt you would get an automated email reply with a pre-filled NDA to sign. Have patience.

Comment: He it's not working. I don't get any reply so what to do now.. :(

Answer (score 0):

What kind of control do you need?
PTZ? Trigger DIDO? Snapshot? Set some camera settings?

Basically, you could do those things by sending CGI requests to camera.
You could check all available CGI commands in the camera user manual.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, VIVOTEK cameras are ONVIF profile S compliant as of late 2009 (see their milestones at http://www.vivotek.com/milestones/ ), so if you don't want to sign an NDA (or if they don't reply in a timely manner), you could theoretically build an interface for the camera off of ONVIF specification, available at http://www.onvif.org/Documents/Specifications.aspx . As a bonus, it has a decent chance of working with a rather lot of other IP cameras as well.